# Webview not loading url from Array

Tags: java, android, webview

When I am running this the webview doesn't load, instead shows only a white screen. The array is a list of URLS. Logcat shows this error

> 11-06 23:36:40.879 25145-25145/live.randomize.abhi.randomize
>   I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process,
>   singleProcess=false 11-06 23:36:40.888
>   25145-25238/live.randomize.abhi.randomize W/cr_ChildProcLauncher:
>   Create a new ChildConnectionAllocator with package name =
>   com.android.chrome, inSandbox = true 11-06 23:36:40.912
>   25145-25145/live.randomize.abhi.randomize D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglCreateContext: 0xa46fdc20: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2 11-06 23:36:40.913
>   25145-25145/live.randomize.abhi.randomize D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglMakeCurrent: 0xa46fdc20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa43334d0) 11-06
>   23:36:41.179 25145-25145/live.randomize.abhi.randomize W/zygote:
>   Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread 11-06
>   23:36:41.195 25145-25225/live.randomize.abhi.randomize
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb45a1a40: ver 2 0 (tinfo
>   0xa4226770) 11-06 23:36:41.293
>   25145-25145/live.randomize.abhi.randomize W/zygote: Attempt to remove
>   non-JNI local reference, dumping thread 11-06 23:36:42.652
>   25145-25145/live.randomize.abhi.randomize W/zygote: Attempt to remove
>   non-JNI local reference, dumping thread 11-06 23:36:42.695
>   25145-25145/live.randomize.abhi.randomize I/chatty: uid=10083(u0_a83)
>   live.randomize.abhi.randomize identical 1 line 11-06 23:36:42.727
>   25145-25145/live.randomize.abhi.randomize W/zygote: Attempt to remove
>   non-JNI local reference, dumping thread 11-06 23:36:42.844
>   25145-25145/live.randomize.abhi.randomize W/zygote: Attempt to remove
>   non-JNI local reference, dumping thread 11-06 23:36:42.925
>   25145-25145/live.randomize.abhi.randomize I/chatty: uid=10083(u0_a83)
>   live.randomize.abhi.randomize identical 1 line 11-06 23:36:42.989
>   25145-25145/live.randomize.abhi.randomize W/zygote: Attempt to remove
>   non-JNI local reference, dumpin

This is the code:- Any Help? Yes I have INTERNET permission in Manifest.

```
private String[] array;
private WebView myWebView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    array = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
    final String randomStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
    {
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView View, WebResourceRequest request)

            {   myWebView.loadUrl(randomStr);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this-

```
    private String[] array;
    private WebView myWebView;
    private ProgressDialog progress;;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        progress = new ProgressDialog(TestActivity.this);
        progress.setTitle("Loading");
        progress.setMessage("Wait until site has finished loading.");
        progress.setCancelable(true);
        progress.show();

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        array = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
        final String randomStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];

        Log.d("TAG: ", randomStr);

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl(randomStr);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if(progress.isShowing()){
                    progress.cancel();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```